# PyQt sms bubble widget

Tags: python, qt, sms, pyqt

I am writing an app in which i want to make show conversation. I am looking for some widget, example, tutorial how to make/paint own widget/view. I want to have smiliar look to iphone sms app.

Greetings.

Comment: [Custom PyQt4 Widget](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/customwidgets/)

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how to custom paint in an overloaded QLabel.  Set a different pen/brush on the painter in the paintEvent to change the color of the bubbles.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Bubble(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,text):
        super(Bubble,self).__init__(text)
        self.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)

    def paintEvent(self, e):

        p = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        p.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing,True)
        p.drawRoundedRect(0,0,self.width()-1,self.height()-1,5,5)

        super(Bubble,self).paintEvent(e)        

class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self,text,left=True):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__()

        hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()

        label = Bubble(text)

        if not left:
            hbox.addSpacerItem(QtGui.QSpacerItem(1,1,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred))

        hbox.addWidget(label)

        if left:
            hbox.addSpacerItem(QtGui.QSpacerItem(1,1,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred))            

        hbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
        self.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = QtGui.QApplication([])
    w = QtGui.QWidget()

    vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()

    vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Left side"))
    vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Right side",left=False))
    vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Left side"))
    vbox.addWidget(MyWidget("Left side"))

    w.setLayout(vbox)
    w.show()

    a.exec_()
```

And you'll end up with something like the following.

[image]

Comment: When do you call `paintEvent`?

Comment: @CheynShmuel. The `paintEvent` method is an event-handler. It is called by Qt whenever the widget needs to be repainted.